# Unable to add config transform

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web.config-transform

I'm trying to add a **Web.Dev.Config** but I'm not able to. When right clicking on the original web config the option "Add config transform" is grayed out. The only config transforms that I have are **Web.Debug.config**, **Web.Release.config** and **Web.Test.Config**.

Why can't I add more?

Comment: Do you have a build configuration named "Dev" for the affected project? The default Visual Studio transformation support is based on the build configuration, so it probably requires the configuration to exist before you can add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to add "Web.Dev.Config" in configuration manager.

[image]